# Keeping the css styling of a custom directive in a separate file

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs

I am learning Angular and I need advice on best practice, and a general direction for digging deeper in the subject:

I am trying to create a web app with Angular which is composed of a number of standalone widgets, and I decided to implemented them each as independent custom directives.

[image]

I would like to make these custom directives as reusable, movable, replaceable and cohesive as possible, and put **all** of their related html/css/js files in their own dedicated folders, with a folder structure of something like this:

[image]

What is the **best practice for loading a separate CSS file for the template partial of a custom directive**? (For example, should I load the CSS from the partial.html which will eventually appear in the html body? Should I look into merging my css files with Grunt upon build?)

Answer (score 0):

You should build all of your CSS into a single file you. Without merging you require an additional request to the server and processing of the CSS which adds more time before the page can be rendered.

For additional loading performance you can combine all of your HTML fragments into a single file as well that you load up front.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="temp2.html">
    <div class="view">
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: totally disagree. Keeping components assets grouped together makes them far more portable and can use tools like grunt or gulp to do the combining for you

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, you can keep the files separate in source but combine them for deployment. The combination would also be a byproduct of running a CSS preprocessor such as LESS if you use those tools.